# Certain fields in .ini files do not get saved if the path name of the .ini is longer than 128 chars

Tags: visual-c++, windows-xp

I am working on a program in Visual Studio 2003 C++ that saves data with .ini files.  The program is already written; it's a full blown windows application that analyses patient data taken from a sleep lab (lots and lots of lines of code).

The program uses .ini files to read and write patient data, such as patient name, patient id, doctor's name...etc.  The other day my boss told me that if the path to the .ini is too long, some of the data does not get saved.

On further inspection I have found out that if the full path name of a .ini file is greater than 128 characters, some of the fields in that .ini file do not get saved to disk.  It's odd because other fields do get saved, while others do not.

I'm not sure, is this an issue with Windows, or could it have to do with the code?  The code uses the GetPrivateProfileString() and WritePrivateProfileString() functions to write to and read from the ini files.  As far as I can see, it treats all the ini files the same and just reads them in when needed and writes to them when the file is saved.

I'm really curious as to why some fields get saved and some do not when the path is greater than 128 characters.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what domain this problem might fall under and what is happening behind the scenes to do this?

Program is written with: 
Visual Studio 2003

The OS is: 
Windows XP

Thank you for any help and insight :)

*********EDIT:
Turns out the code uses the OpenFile function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430(VS.85).aspx to open the ini files and this only allows for a max of 128 chars.

I'm going to try and change functionality to the CreateFile function without breaking the code....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere in your code there is a filename CHAR buffer of 128 bytes.  Depending on what the codepath is, use of a longer filename string in that buffer may or may not work. It's quite possible that some writes might work and others fail, though if your code handles errors properly you would think you would find out about the failures through suitable error logs.

Comment: Turns out it uses an out dated function called OpenFile() to load the ini and OpenFile() only accepts max 128 char path naames.